# Typo3 tx_news category menu: Show only used categories

Tags: typo3, tx-news

By default, the category menu of tx_news shows all categories.

How it is possible to display only categories to which at least one news entry exist?

It is annoying for the user, if he clicks on a category but the are no news yet under that category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to know from the extension point of view what "is used" means as this could be restricted by a folder, additional constraints like time, archive, ...

Therefore this feature is not available by default. If you need it, create a simple VH and use the category as argument and then check with a DB query if this category is used in your project.

Comment: But if it is possible for the "Date menu", it should also be possible for "Category menu"!?

Comment: the date menu action needs the same configuration as e.g. the list action. however, feel free to come up with a PR